# Magento date from string

Tags: php, date, magento

I've exported reviews from mysql db in a csv format, and I've included created_at field. Now, when I open CSV file, date is in following format: `2014-02-04 13:31:43`. So, I now want to import those reviews into different website, and everything works except for created_at date, for which I'm using following code:

```
// $_row['created_at'] = '2014-02-04 13:31:43';
// $_review is the object I created with
// $_review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
$_created_at = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($_row['created_at'], 'medium', false);
$_review->setCreatedAt($_created_at);
```

but that doesn't set created_at properly. What's the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: does $_created_at has value?

Comment: Yes, string(12) "4. feb. 2014".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
$createdtime = new Zend_Date(strtotime($_row['created_at']));
$_created_at = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('M d, Y', $createdtime);
$_review->setCreatedAt($_created_at);
```

Comment: Nope. Still creates a date as if I used time();